# Является ли вводным оборот "как минимум"?

Tags: пунктуация

Фраза такая: "Писать безграмотно(,) как минимум(,) стыдно". Что-то я уже путаюсь: нужно тут оборот "как минимум" выделять запятыми или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайте Грамота.ру указано, что это наречное выражение, которое постановки запятых не требует. 
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_325. Но!!! Если Вы выделяете этот оборот интонационно в устной речи, то запятые на письме допускаются.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще нюансы http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.42.  Конструкция может обособляться, теряя синтаксические связи, в начале предложения. И если ее можно "развернуть" (распространить) до отдельного предложения. 
   Я так понимаю, что "как минимум" - очень спорная конструкция!